# Como disparar uma Action do Redux sem um component React

Tags: react, axios, redux

Olá, estou criando um [interceptor](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors) para o [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) que, se caso minha response houver um erro com o status [Forbidden (403)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) o mesmo precisa disparar a Action que inicia o logoff do usuário para forçá-lo a reautenticar.

> Isso é necessário porque ela dispara uma série de ações em cascata e já está configurada para tal recurso.

O meu problema é que não sei como conectar uma função ao redux sem ter um componente do React. Até o momento meu interceptor está dessa forma:

```js
import axios from 'axios'
import { logoffRequest } from 'store/actions/userActions'

axios.interceptors.response.use(
  response => response,
  error => {
    if (403 === error.response.status) {
      logoffRequest()
    }
  }
)
```

A action `logoffRequest` depende de um redux para que funcione porque ela mexe em um monte de estados da aplicação, inclusive enviando dados ao backend...

O que eu preciso fazer para que seja possível chamar essa Action de dentro desse interceptor?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode obter uma instância da sua `store` e usar o `dispatch`.

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { logoffRequest } from 'store/actions/userActions'
import { store } from '/caminho'


axios.interceptors.response.use(
  response => response,
  error => {
    if (403 === error.response.status) {
      store.dispatch(logoffRequest())
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: Mas se eu fizer isso, quando eu puxar a store de um arquivo eu vou ta chamando novamente a criação dela e vou perder as informações não?

Comment: @LeandroLuk acredito que não, testou esse código?

Comment: não cheguei a testar, eu resolvi encapsulando a declaração dos interceptors dentro de uma função que recebe a store em si.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver meu problema colocando a declaração dos interceptors em uma função que recebe a store, assim eu posso chamar essa criação dos interceptors logo após a criação da store no `index.js` assim:

**src/lib/axios.interceptors.js**

```js
import axios from 'axios'
import { logoffRequest } from 'store/actions/userActions'

export default store => {
  axios.interceptors.response.use(
    response => response,
    error => {
      if (403 === error.response.status) {
        store.dispatch(logoffRequest())
      }
    }
  )
}
```

**src/index.js**

```js
// ... outros imports (pra reduzir o exemplo...)

import axiosInterceptors from './lib/axios-interceptors'

const store = configureStore(history, initialState)
const rootElement = document.getElementById('*')

axiosInterceptors(store)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <Views />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  rootElement
)
```

Dessa forma eu tenho a garantia que a aplicação irá iniciar contendo o interceptor e que o mesmo está usando a store única e correta que está sendo passada ao projeto geral.